# Does String.format(%X, num) work only for integers?

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert a decimal number to hexa.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double num_in = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.print(String.format("%X", num_in));
    }
```

I got an error message below after running this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: x != java.lang.Double
```

The code works when I put an integer instead of double.

I've tried %X%f, %X,%f and these have the error as well. And I found others use double numbers with String.format(). I cannot find any format limitation of arg in String.format(). Is String.format() unavailable to convert decimal double number to hexa?

Comment: First `sc.nextInt()` will return an `int` (not sure why you want to widen that to a `double`). Also, not clear what result you would expect. Try `System.out.println(Double.toHexString(Math.PI));`

Comment: Thanks for finding my mistake. sc.nextInt() was typo caused while I copied and pasted my code. Same error occurs when I use sc.nextDouble().

Comment: `%X` is not the appropriated choice for this operation. You are looking perhaps for `%A` Please refer to the docs: [Class Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Comment: The doc helps to know a reason for the error. Really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not clear. You can't really 'print a double in hex'.

State an example input and the kind of output you desire.

## Example 1

Input: `12.11`
desired output: `C.B`

## Example answer

that makes no sense whatsoever. Imagine the input is `12.10` and thus your desired output would be `C.A`, except `12.10` is the same as `12.1`, and thus `C.A` makes no sense.

## Example 2

Input: `12.11`
Desired output: `C.(something that makes sense here)`

There's some tricky math involved here. .11 is '1 1/10th + 1 1/100th'. The equivalent in hexadecimal would be '? 1/16th + ? 1/256th + ? 1/4096th' and so on. Converting .11 to this is an infinite expansion, the way 1 divided by 3 never ends (it's 0.33333333 forever). 10 is not evenly divisible in 16, you see.

## Example 3

Input: `12.11`
Desired output: `C.11`

## Answer

That's.. bizarre, but if you want that, okay. Obviously, given that it is arbitrary and nonsensical, there is no one format letter to do this. Separate out the integral part and the fractional part and print them separately (each gets its own letter). Something like:

```
long integral = (long) numIn;
double fractional = numIn - integral; // for large numbers this fails, take care.
String fracString = String.format("%.4f", fractional).substring(1); // lop off the 0.
return String.format("%X", integral) + fracString;
```

NB: In general hexadecimal fractions aren't a thing.

## Example 4

I want the bit representation of that double value in memory (according to the [IEEE754 spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)).

## Answer

```
System.out.printf("%X", Double.doubleToLongBits(numIn));
```

note that this will look nothing like the number in decimal, see the wikipedia page that explains how this stuff is stored (which is complicated).